# Antivirus API  on Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to get the information of antivirus product installed on my Mac-machine. I'm developing an app which will show all system information, and I'm able to get system basic info, but not able to the get the security details, like what all antivirus/antispyware products installed in that machine.

I'm developing my app using Obj-C, and trying to get the api in that only. I want to call that api on demand, so it could directly embedded within the app or can execute externally as well. If I could get that command also then I could use that.

Does anyone know what API I should be calling please?

Comment: I don't think there's an API to list antivirus apps… I would imagine you'd have to hardcode the names of popular apps.

Answer (score 2):

OPSWAT maintains a commercial C++ library/api called OESIS Framework which enables the integrator to obtain information and manage common functions of 3rd party security applications installed on Mac OS devices.

The list of security applications that can be called is at- http://www.opswat.com/products/oesis-framework/supported-applications#!product=all&os=mac

Available API calls, by application type are at http://www.opswat.com/products/oesis-framework/available-apis

Disclaimer: I work for OPSWAT.